# Drop down menu in display file for AS400

Tags: drop-down-menu, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

In AS400,is it possible to have a drop down menu within a display file "RECORD" type record format.

```
I have created a menu that is written in CL program and invokes the respective 
RPG programs for each option selected.
```

But for one of the options i would further like to open up a menu,a sub menu rather on the same screen(like a drop down).I am aware of a record type of drop down in display...but how do i invoke that through CL i am unsure.

Please help folks.

Answer (score 2):

One displays the window record format the same way one displays the main record format.  SNDRCVF (or with a SNDF followed by a RCVF).  CL doesn't allow for subfiles, but aside from that, there isn't any special technique to work with a window record format in CL.  I know that this sounds very theoretical, but it is the best that I can do without seeing the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
0000.01 WELCOMEQQ,1
0000.10 0001 WRKMBRPDM
0000.11 0002 GO MENU(GIRRAJ111/MENU#1)
0000.12 0003 GO MENU(QGPL/GUEST)
0000.13 0004 GO MENU(QGPL/GUEST)
0000.14 0011 signoff
```

here welcomeqq is my first menu 
and here MENU#1,GUEST these my secondary Menu which is the optin of first menu

{ Finally you should use "GO MENU(library name/menu name)"  this command behind ur opt.}

Answer (score 0):

Since this needs to be implemented using CL, one possible option you can try, is using indicators and switching the option line on/off accordingly which will be in the same record. 
Well there can be a hidden flaw, all options are always on (unless you declare the fields with particular values you want to receive), just that it is hidden  (if the user type a hidden option that too gets triggered)